# ¿Se usan los aumentativos con participios o adjetivos?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, participio, diminutivos, aumentativos

El otro día mientras íbamos en el coche, la pequeña se quedó dormida en su asiento y nuestro hijo mayor, sabiendo que a veces decimos que se ha quedado "dormidita" (usando el diminutivo cariñoso), quiso darle una vuelta de tuerca y trató de usar un aumentativo, supongo que para expresar que estaba muy dormida, y le salió "dormidón", aunque supongo que "dormidota" habría sido otra opción.

Eso me dejó pensando, y es que los aumentativos y diminutivos se suelen usar de forma más común con los sustantivos, y entonces su sentido es más o menos literal (de "mesa", "mesita" para indicar una mesa de pequeño tamaño, por ejemplo, o de "cochazo" para indicar un coche grande o de grandes prestaciones). Pero con los participios o adjetivos la cosa cambia. Que yo sepa, solo se usan los diminutivos, y cuando le dices a alguien que vaya "rapidito" no es un "rápido pequeño", ni cuando alguien está "dormidito" es un "dormido pequeño". Aquí los diminutivos no son literales, sino figurados, y se usan con distintos énfasis, para indicar desde cariño y familiaridad hasta incluso sarcasmo o malicia.

Sin embargo, ¿se usan en algún caso (o región) los aumentativos con adjetivos o participios para indicar algún tipo de énfasis concreto?

Comment: Supongo que ya lo has pensado, pero en los adjetivos ya existen los superlativos para enfatizar, lo que puede hacer el aumentativo superfluo. Dicho esto, creo recordar haber conocido a alguien de Ecuador que usaba "-azo" para el superlativo, como "cansadazo". La página 178 de [esta fuente](https://helencg1980.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/14-h-toscano-mateus-el-espac3b1ol-en-el-ecuador-libro-de-apoyo.pdf) parece darme la razón. Quizá algún local lo puede confirmar.

Comment: @wimi ciertamente, aunque reconozco que ese día se me pasó indicarle al mayor que quería decir "dormidísima", supongo que estábamos ocupados riéndonos por la ocurrencia. También habría valido decir que estaba "requetedormida".

Answer (score 2):

Con participios y adjetivos usamos mayormente diminutivos, generalmente afectuosos o tendientes a restar relevancia a alguna condición negativa(*) (*flaquito, buenito, calentito*) y despectivos (feúcho, debilucho, tontuelo), y sólo raramente aumentativos (tal como dijo @wimi, para aumentar tenemos los superlativos).

Se me ocurren por ahora los adjetivos (muchas veces sustantivados):

- grandulón, na

  1. adj. coloq. Am. Grandullón, especialmente si se comporta como un niño. U. m. en sent. despect.
- gordinflón, na
  De gordo e inflar.

  1. adj. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Demasiado gruesa. U. t. c. s.
- buenazo, za
  Del aum. de bueno.

  1. adj. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Pacífica o de buen natural. U. t. c. s.

"gilazo" es aumentativo de "gil":

- gil

  1. adj. Arg. y Ur. Dicho de una persona: simple (‖ incauta). U. t. c. s.

En Argentina, también tenemos aumentativos como "rapidona" para referirnos a una mujer fácil, rápida de seducir.

(*) En Argentina, al menos, se usan muchas veces eufemismos simpáticos para aminorar la negatividad de una cualidad, utilizando palabras que empiezan con los mismos fonemas que la cualidad negativa en cuestión: en lugar de decir que algo o alguien es lento, decimos que es "lenteja", o en lugar de decir que es duro, decimos que es "durazno", o en lugar de decir que es corto, decimos que es "cortina".

Answer (score 2):

Por la misma naturaleza de los adjetivos y adverbios no podría esperarse que los aumentativos y diminutivos que fueran aplicados a ellos fueran literales, ya que se refiere a cualidades y no a objetos concretos, pero en realidad esto tampoco vale para muchos sustantivos abstractos (una "mentirita" no es literalmente una mentira pequeña sino una mentira de poca importancia).

Los aumentativos sobre adjetivos y adverbios podrían funcionar como intensificadores (similares a *requete-*) y los diminutivos como que sea que se llame a lo contrario de un intensificador (existe la idea de "atenuador", pero es algo diferente). En castellano contamos ya con un intensificador estándar, *-ísimo*, de manera que otros por fuerza serán considerados informales, slang, o una ocurrencia, pero esto no quita que podrían ser en teoría aceptados, como ya lo son *re-, requete-, recontra-*, la serie *super-, mega-, hiper-*, y otros similares.

Los sufijos diminutivos estándar parecen más propensos a unirse a adjetivos como anti-intensificadores, pero la mayoría de las veces son de hecho sólo expresivos. Si estoy un poco cansado diré que estoy *un poco cansado*, no *cansadito* salvo con algún sentido particular (que irá más allá de mi grado de cansancio). Si digo que dejé mi habitación *acomodadita* no será porque la haya acomodado poco o a medias o que la habitación sea pequeña.

Incluso cuando el adjetivo refiere más o menos literalmente a una cualidad física, hay un componente expresivo en el diminutivo: el niño ya está *grandecito*, la habitación es *pequeñita*.

Con los aumentativos pasa lo mismo, salvo que son mucho menos comunes con adjetivos, al menos en el lenguaje de los adultos. Los niños sí pueden decir cosas como *dormidota* o *grandototón* (ejemplo real) pero aquí los sufijos pierden contra los prefijos que ya mencioné antes.

Dado que los diminutivos tienden a ser casi exclusivamente expresivos y que los aumentativos ya tienen una forma diferente de manifestarse entre los adjetivos, no creo que se puedan encontrar muchos ejemplos de uso de unos o de otros con significado literal.

Answer (score 1):

He oído 'dormidota' en español, creo que no está aceptado por la RAE y es puramente slang o español de la calle.

'Está toda dormidota'

Comment: Yo he oído "dormidota" pero como sustantivo. "Juan se metió una dormidota". Siendo así esto no responde la pregunta. Tal vez si adicionas ejemplos del uso que haz escuchado sería mejor. Además escribe tu respuesta en español ya que la pregunta se formuló en español.